# Issue deploying application to Mule 3.7

Tags: deployment, mule

I am facing issue with Mule 3.7.0

I have been trying to deploy an existing working application to Mule 3.7.0.

If fails printing an error. I couldn't debug from the error. 
The error printed is not showing anything in related to the application code.
The same application works fine in Mule 3.6.1 and Mule 3.3

But it fails giving the following error.

```
ERROR 2015-08-05 12:24:37,863 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'myapp', see below  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: NullPointerException: 
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) ~[mule-module-boot-ee-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run(WrapperManager.java:4163) ~[wrapper-3.5.26.jar:3.5.26]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null (java.lang.NullPointerException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[?:?]
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[?:?]
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.HashSet.contains(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[?:?]
    ... 18 more
INFO  2015-08-05 12:24:37,870 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-08-05 12:24:37,915 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 
**********************************************************************
*              - - + DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* default                                       * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
* myapp                                         * default                        * FAILED             *
*******************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I'm suffering a similar problem - All my apps deploy OK except one, and I can't work out what's wrong with it. It's strange that just one fails - implies that the answer below shouldn't be the issue, but I'll check that too.

Comment: I'm suspecting APIKit... the apps the don't run for me, both use that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below are satisfied:

1. Your JDK and Anypoint studio/Mule ESB are of same bit architecture(either 32 or 64bit).
2. Mule 3.7's JDK prerequisite is JDK1.7. Try upgrading to JDK1.7, if your current JDK version is older than recommended.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be an old version of ApiKit (1.6.1) which needed upgrading manually to 1.7.1 by editing pom.xml for the projects concerned.